# 98 Chevy Malibu 2.4 liter has fuel and fire but will not start

Tags: starting, chevrolet, diagnostics, malibu

98 chevy malibu 2.4 liter .Has fuel to injectors  and fire to the plugs but won't start?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you checked for codes? Have you checked your fuel injection circuits (relay/fuses)?

Comment: What happens when you try to start? Does it crank strong but never catch?